# Customise log line in Airflow logs

Tags: logging, configuration, format, airflow, settings

I am trying to modify the log lines with in Airflow logs to include dag id in each of the log lines. And I see there is a log_format parameter where we can sent how we want log lines. As out airflow runs in the docker I tried with the env variable as below, but it does not seem to work.

- AIRFLOW__CORE__LOG_FORMAT=[%(asctime)s] {{%(filename)s:%(lineno)d}} %(levelname)s - %(ti.dag_id)s - %(message)s

Does anybody help how we can add dag id in each line of logs. the airflow version we use is 1.10.9